# Вывод всего контекста

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Имеется такой код:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class MainFormView(DataMixin, FormView):
    form_class = MainForm
    template_name = 'sitee/index.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['menu_selected'] = 'home'
        c_def = self.get_user_context(title="Главная")
        return dict(list(context.items()) + list(c_def.items()))

#index.html
...
<title>{{title}}</title>
...
```

Можно ли вывести все переменные одной командой? Наподобии `{{ output_context_dump }}` в следствии чего выведутся все элементы, которые находятся здесь `dict(list(context.items()) + list(c_def.items()))`

Comment: Для чего Вам это нужно? В целях тестирования?

Comment: да, не известно, что передается на страницу, правда сейчас появилась идея прям во view принтом это вывести

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Для целей тестирования

Вы можете воспользоваться шаблонным тегом [`debug`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#debug). Он выводит отладочную информацию, которая будет включать весь контекст:

```py
# index.html
{% debug %}
```

Comment: Спасибо!!! Идеально!!!